# SQL: Re-Index/Re-Build Entire DB

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I am tired of re-indexing/re-building every table I have, is there any way to do this to an entire database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to use someone else's maintenance scripts.  [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/) are the best known and free, but [Minion Ware also has a free reindex script](http://minionware.net/reindex/).

If you can't do that for some reason,  something like this might work:

```
Use YourDB

Declare @TBname nvarchar(255),
        @SQL nvarchar(max) 


select @TBname = min(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'

while @TBname is not null

BEGIN
    set @SQL='ALTER INDEX ALL ON [' + @TBname + '] REBUILD;'
    --print @SQL
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    select @TBname = min(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' and TABLE_NAME > @TBname          
END
```

Comment: Ooo nice, I will let you know if these work. Thank you!